# Remove element arrayin php

Tags: php, arrays

How to remove value in array that contains a keyword ?. I have tried function `unset` array, but it doesn't work.

```
 $labels=array("FullName"=>"Full name",
                        "Email"=>"Email",
                        "LoginName"=>"Login",
                        "Password"=>"Password",
                        "PasswordConfirm"=>"Confirm Your password");
```

I need to delete the `PasswordConfirm` and its value.

Comment: unset($labels['PasswordConfirm']);

Comment: unset should work. Please post the code you tried.

Comment: Opp sorry I typed unset($labels[4]). That why it doesn;t work.

Answer (score 2):

`unset` would work just fine:

```
$labels=array("FullName"=>"Full name",
                        "Email"=>"Email",
                        "LoginName"=>"Login",
                        "Password"=>"Password",
                        "PasswordConfirm"=>"Confirm Your password");

unset ($labels['Password'], $labels['PasswordConfirm']);
print_r($labels);
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ap9-dqj).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, thank you.  I was actually on a different service when y ou posted this :)  Thank you again for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just unset only the 'PasswordConfirm' key to delete the PasswordConfirm and its value.

```
$labels=array("FullName"=>"Full name",
                    "Email"=>"Email",
                    "LoginName"=>"Login",
                    "Password"=>"Password",
                    "PasswordConfirm"=>"Confirm Your password");

 unset ($labels['PasswordConfirm']);
 print_r($labels);
```